# Paypal express checkout -DoExpressCheckout in sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am working on to implement paypal express checkout in sand box .

my flow were

1.Set express checkout 
2.After payment (by using paypal website) redirecting our own site
3. Calling "DoExpressCheckoutPayment"

my problem is always i get 
[CHECKOUTSTATUS] => PaymentActionNotInitiated in the response and not happening the transaction too.

My response was like below when i call GetExpressCheckoutDetails

```
(
    [TOKEN] => EC%2d6X954162JY449332N
    [BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS] => 0
    ***[CHECKOUTSTATUS] => PaymentActionNotInitiated***
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015%2d03%2d03T06%3a13%3a44Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 5ae26bdbf091f
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 109%2e0
    [BUILD] => 15558997
    [EMAIL] => jazeem%2elk%2dbuyer%40gmail%2ecom
    [PAYERID] => QNHANS6NY52GY
    [PAYERSTATUS] => verified
    [FIRSTNAME] => Test
    [LASTNAME] => Buyer
    [COUNTRYCODE] => US
    [SHIPTONAME] => Jeremy%20V%2e%20White
    [SHIPTOSTREET] => 44%20Main%20street
    [SHIPTOCITY] => Boston
    [SHIPTOSTATE] => MA
    [SHIPTOZIP] => 02134
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => United%20States
    [ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [AMT] => 150%2e00
    [ITEMAMT] => 150%2e00
    [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0%2e00
    [HANDLINGAMT] => 0%2e00
    [TAXAMT] => 0%2e00
    [INSURANCEAMT] => 0%2e00
    [SHIPDISCAMT] => 0%2e00
    [L_NAME0] => Test%20Product0
    [L_NUMBER0] => H0015EXYM6
    [L_QTY0] => 1
    [L_TAXAMT0] => 0%2e00
    [L_AMT0] => 150%2e00
    [L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 150%2e00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 150%2e00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 0%2e00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT] => 0%2e00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 0%2e00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT] => 0%2e00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT] => 0%2e00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED] => false
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME] => Jeremy%20V%2e%20White
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET] => 44%20Main%20street
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY] => Boston
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE] => MA
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP] => 02134
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => United%20States
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSNORMALIZATIONSTATUS] => None
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Test%20Product0
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0] => H0015EXYM6
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0] => 0%2e00
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 150%2e00
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
)
```

Thanks
AZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats was my mistake , i mean i didnt pass the parameters properly when i call DoExpressCheckout.